# BEM and css frameworks

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, bem

How to use BEM methodology with css frameworks, for instance Bootstrap? If I have following markup structure is it ok? :

```
 <div class="hero">
    <div class="container">
       <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 mx-auto">
          <h1 class="hero__title"></h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

or shouild I structure document like this:

```
<div class="hero">
  <div class="hero__container">
    <div class="hero__row">
      <div class="hero__row-inner">
        <h1 class="hero__title"></h1>
      </div>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you shouldn't try to apply the BEM methodology for utility classes like "container, row, col" and more, but you can try helper situations `col col--xs-12` or `img img--cover`

You can check more utility classes in the bootstrap doc; https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/borders/

```
<div class="hero">
  <div class="container">
       <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 mx-auto">
          <h1 class="hero__title"></h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You had better use it as your first code blocks.

Comment: Well, thanks for the reply, I know about bootstrap helpers classes I've even used them in example above (mx-auto). Some time ago I've read on BEM website's forum that this methodology dont intend usage of helper classes. So Is it allowed to take a part of methodology like naming? Because I dont want to constantly repeat myself doing  modifiers like this .hero__title--text-center rather than .hero__title.text-center.  or .hero__title.mb-1.